# Subconsulta All SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Estoy leyendo un tutorial SQL y hay algo que no logro comprender completamente.
una definicion de All en una subconsulta dice que hará lo siguiente:

Queremos saber si TODAS las editoriales que publicaron libros de "Borges" coinciden con TODAS las editoriales que publicaron libros de "Richard Bach":

```
select titulo
  from libros
  where autor='Borges' and
  codigoeditorial = all
   (select e.codigo
    from editoriales e
    join libros l
    on codigoeditorial=e.codigo
    where l.autor='Richard Bach');
```

Comprendo que valida que todas las editoriales de libros de Borges coincidan con el resultado de la subconsulta de editoriales de libros de Richard Bach.
Pero en el siguiente ejemplo marca lo siguiente:

El precio de cada libro de "Borges" es comparado con cada valor de la lista de valores retornada por la subconsulta; si cumple la condición, es decir, si es mayor a TODOS los precios de "Richard Bach" (o al mayor), se lista.

```
  from libros
  where autor='borges' and
  precio > all
   (select precio
    from libros
    where autor='bach');
```

Mi confusión es que no comprendo la diferencia entre estos dos ejemplos; en uno dice que verifica que todas las editoriales que publicaron libros de Borges coinciden con todas las editoriales de Richard Bach.
el segundo ejemplo compara el precio de cada libro de Borges  si es mayor que todos los de Richard Bach.
Por que uno compara todos con  todos y el segundo ejemplo compara uno con todos?

Comment: Te recomiendo que no te estreses mucho con las clausulas ALL, ANY o SOME. En la vida real nadie las usa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se que tutorial estas viendo, pero creo que solo estas confundiendo la terminologia, la traducción o simplemente esta mal explicado.

La clausula [ALL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/all-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) es un comparador. Se usa en conjunción con el resto de los comparadores (=, >=, <=, etc...) para comparar un valor, contra una lista, y tiene que cumplir la condicion para todas las comparaciones.

En tu primer ejemplo, por cada registro en libros, que sean de borges, busca la editorial y esa editorial la compara contra TODAS (el ALL) las editoriales de Bach. Eso lo hace por cada fila!

En el segundo caso pasa lo mismo. Pero recorda, lo hace por cada fila! entonces por cada libro, verifica que el precio sea mayor a todos los libros de Bach.

Ahora, tene en cuenta algo. Salvo que Bach (en el caso 1) haya publicado con una sola editorial, la condicion no se va a cumplir nunca. Porque si tiene 2 editoriales, cada registro le daria true y false en cada caso..

Lo que devuelve esta consulta es cada fila que va cumpliendo con la condición.